# exceptions in wpf designer on windows 8

Tags: wpf, windows-8, designer

We just installed the released windows 8 for Enterprise. The project is still under .Net 4.0 and VS 2010 (the same as in windows 7), there are always error when loading the designer:
Provide value on 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder' threw an exception.

The errors point to staticResource we defined somewhere else, which are the style, color, etc. All these resources are already included in resource dictionary (app.xaml) in a certain order. The same code works fine in windows 7.

Running the project is fine, but we cannot open the designer. How could we solve this issue? Thank you all in advance.